# Confused about ory hydra / Google Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-identity, ory-hydra

I have a project where I need to use Google Identity Platform to store user accounts (related to application A) in GCP and ORY hydra to connect user in an application B with that same account of app A (I think like “connect with google” butoon , I must create “connect with application A” button).

I ran the docker oauth client and ory server on ports 9010, 9001 and cretated a small login , consent providers to test and I get the final step is a token.

BUT the image is still blurry to me, can you please help me understand what should be the flow, what is the clients , servers , providers regarding Application A and Application B ? and the general flow / definition I should do ?

And in Google Identity Platform , there are " Identity Providers " , should I set a “Email/Password” for Application A and “OpenID Connect” for Application B ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**
[image: Google Identity Platform]

Here is the page to include an OIDC provider, what should I put here (regarding Hydra) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use  Cloud Identity Platform as an IdP (Identity Provider). However, you can reuse the setup option of the projet A, in your application B

[image]

And you should have to add the application B URL as authorized domain in the OAuth consent screen page

[image]

However, all the authentication mechanism will be handle by Firebase auth and not by Hydra. It's maybe not what you want...